# How to use deep link in android

Tags: java, android, deep-linking

In my application i want use deep link for open urls with my application.
I write below codes, but when click on URL open this URLs in browser and not open in my app.

**My manifest codes :**

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.PostDetailsActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/DetailsActivityTheme" >
    <!-- DeepLink -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="www.example.ir"
            android:pathPrefix="/*"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="example.ir"
            android:pathPrefix="/*"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**My java codes:**

```
Intent intent2 = getIntent();
Uri data = intent2.getData();
if (data!=null){
    Toast.makeText(mActivity, ""+data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**My url :** `http://example.ir/2018/06/24/content_title_url`

How can i fix this issue and open into my app?

Comment: add host android:host="example.ir" in your menidfest instead of android:host="www.example.ir"

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan, please see my above codes. i write each host names, example.ir and www.example.ir . but nor work to me! can you help me more? please

Comment: sure I recently done this task . Deeplink with firebase.

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan, firebase is boycott in my country :(

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan, why not work my codes?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan, i set 2018 for pathprefix but not work anagin

Comment: please add android:autoVerify="true" in intent filter like this <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan not work :( :(